# I have set up a function with a double for loop to calculate a summation over different arrays. Why does my function always return 0?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

[SCD summation formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLmur.png)

I was given a double summation formula to code in python. Basically, I was given 30 different arrays with different arrangements of e and k values, which correspond to a negative charge or a positive charge. Those charges are qm and qn in the summation, so qm = -1 and qn = 1. The relative positions of e are denoted as m, and for k they are denoted as n. Those are m and n in the summation. The arrays are named as s1, s2, s3, s4, etc... all the way to s30. I will include a sample array here for s3 and s4, so you know what I am talking about.

s3 is given by `s3 = np.array( ['k','e','k','k','k','e','k','k','e','e','k','k','e','e','k','e','k','e','k','e','k','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','k','e','k','e','k','e','k','k','k','e','e','k','e','k','e','e','k','k','e','e','e','e'])`

s4 is given by `s4 = np.array( ['k','e','k','e','k','k','e','e','k','e','k','k','e','e','e','k','k','e','k','e','k','e','k','k','k','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','k','e','e','k','k','e','e','k','k','k','e','e','k','e','e','e','k','e'])`

So, now I defined finding the position as n_value for 'k' and m_value for 'e'. Those functions are as follows

for m_value

```
def m_value(position_num, array_name):
"""
same as for the n_value, except for 'e' instead of 'k'
"""
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(array_name)):
        if array_name[i]=='e':
            cnt+=1
        if cnt==position_num:
            return i+1
    return 0
```

For n_value

```
def n_value(position_num, array_name):
"""
this is a function to get all of the positions of 
'k' in the array entered.
    position_num = what number 'k' value you want (1st, 2nd, etc...)
    array_name = what scd row (s1, s2, etc...)
define the specific element of the array 
returns value of where the 'k' is in the given sequence
"""
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(array_name)):
        if array_name[i]=='k':
            cnt+=1
        if cnt==position_num:
            return i+1
    return 0
```

Then, I defined the charges of both e and k, respectively

```
charge_values = {'e' : -1, 'k' : 1}
```

e_charge= charge_values['e']
k_charge= charge_values['k']

and defined an N value to count to

```
N = 50
```

Finally, I wrote a definition for the function to sum up according to the summation formula given me, defined as 'SCD'. Here it is

```
def SCD(array_name):
"""
this should sum all of the elements in accordance with the
SCD summation formula. see notes to see full layout of 
formula and elements
"""
    summ = 0.0
    nposition_num=0
    mposition_num=0
    for m in range(2, N):
        summ = 0.0
        mposition_num = m_value(m, array_name)
        qm = mposition_num*e_charge
        for n in range (0, m-1):
            nposition_num= n_value(n, array_name)
            qn = nposition_num*k_charge
            summ += qm*qn*np.sqrt(m-n)
        summ += summ
    summ = (summ/float(N))     
    return summ
```

Now, here a major problem arises. No matter what array it is, the value returned for SCD is always 0.0. I know this to be inaccurate, so I was wondering what logical or coding errors I was making in this to cause the output to always yield a zero. I am new to python, so any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have two versions of `summ` in mind, an outer and an inner. If so, you should use different names for them. But alternatively, you *can* do this with one `summ`, but then don't reset it with the inner `summ = 0` and don't then do `summ += summ`, as ... it is already there ;-)

Comment: That did seem to work better, thank you. I get why deleting it in the first loop works, as it has already been defined above. But why delete the summ +=summ in the second loop, because shouldn't I want the new value of the summ? or is that already taken care of in the summ += qn*qm*np.sqrt(m-n)?

Comment: Indeed, that already happened in the inner loop. Look at what leaving it in would mean: add my own value to myself. It will double the current sum.

Comment: Thank you. This may be a more conceptual question than can be answered here, but how can I be sure that the code is summing exactly how I want it to, besides doing out an entire array by hand, which would take hours? Is there a part of debugging I am missing?

Comment: [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) to test your code.  That's how you verify the expected results of a function.

Comment: Ok thank you all for the help